# Loading Comma Separated csv file to table in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008, msbi, ssis-2005

I have a csv file with below formatted data.

> File: Sample.csv
>
> Id,Name,Address
>
> 1,Abcd,street1,3rdcross,xxxx
>
> 2,Cfre,2ndmain,3rdstreet,yyy
>
> 3,Asdf,4thmain,1stcross,zzz

Need to load the data to table like below.

> Table: Sample
>
> Id   Name  Address
>
> 1    Abcd  street1,3rdcross,xxxx
>
> 2    Cfre  2ndmain,3rdstreet,yyy
>
> 3    Asdf  4thmain,1stcross,zzz

How to acheive this using SSIS ?

If we use a comma delimiter, then the address column will split into 3 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Initially when Text Qualifier is set to none, the columns are separated.

[image]

When changed Text Qualifier to double quoted " then it was perfect.

[image]

Comment: So your file doesn't look like what you asked in your question. The third column actually has quotes around it.

Answer (score 1):

If you your data is consistently 5 columns but your header isn't then skip row 1 and name the columns as you want.

Possibly:

```
Id,Name,Address,Directions,[Blah]
```

If you really want to put those back into a `","` delimited field as you stated then used derived column and concatenate.

```
new column = Address + "," + Directions + "," + [Blah]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done from derived column transformation by follwing the following steps:

1. In Flat File Connection Manager select format as Ragged Right and not delimited. So your data will be coming in one column
2. select derived column transformation. create 3 columns in this transformation with the below mentioned formula's:

   ```
   ID - SUBSTRING([Id,Name,Address],1,FINDSTRING([Id,Name,Address],",",1) - 1)

   Name - SUBSTRING([Id,Name,Address],FINDSTRING([Id,Name,Address],",",1) + 1,FINDSTRING([Id,Name,Address],",",2) - FINDSTRING([Id,Name,Address],",",1) - 1)

   Address - SUBSTRING([Id,Name,Address],FINDSTRING([Id,Name,Address],",",3) + 1,LEN([Id,Name,Address]))
   ```

This is how you can get three seperate columns from the text file.